# Android viewpager online content

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using the 'Jake Wharton' https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator
and i'm trying to use it with online content.

The idea is, i get a JSON array. For each object in the array i want to create a view in the viewpager. The object itself will contain some text to be added in each vew and a url that will be used to load a pic.

So, if you know any tutorial or you have an idea of how i should built this, speak up!

Comment: Post what you came up with if it doens't works... We can't do it for you oO this is to specific

Comment: I created a video tutorial that covers this: http://youtu.be/JqFkkXMwWDg If you follow along with that example you should have the basic understanding you need to re-purpose the example to work with your data set.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Thanks, i will watch the video and study the sample code